# VS2010 development web server does not use integrated-mode HTTP handlers/modules

Tags: visual-studio, httphandler, web-config, httpmodule

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 2 web site, targeted for .NET Framework 4.0, using Visual Studio 2010.

My web.config contains the following code:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="XhtmlModule" type="DomenicDenicola.Website.XhtmlModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="DotLess" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" path="*.less" verb="*" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

When I use `Build > Publish` to put the web site on my local IIS7 instance, it works great.

However, when I use `Debug > Start Debugging`, neither the HTTP handler nor module are executed on any requests.

Strangely enough, when I put the handler and module `<add />` tags back into `<system.web />` under `<httpHandlers />` and `<httpModules />`, they work. This seems to imply that the development web server is running in classic mode.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't. **WebDev.WebServer.exe** does not and cannot support integrated pipeline.

So, if you have code that cannot be written to perform in both environments you will need to use a local IIS for development.

Basically, `system.web` is the place to configure webdev server and IIS5-6 handlers and modules. `system.webServer` is for IIS7 handlers and modules, as you know.

**Reference**:

Each request in **WebDev.WebHost40** (and previous versions) is processed by `HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest` 
 ([which does not support integrated pipeline mode](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/308352/httpruntime-processrequest-does-not-work-in-iis7-integrated-pipeline-mode)). This is the method used in all three versions of **WebHost.WebServer.dll** (the core of **WebDev.WebServer.exe**)

And the word of [some dude](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/team/view) who is fairly familiar with the inner workings of Cassini/WebDev by virtue of managing [this project](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/). ;-)

Comment: I'll assume you're right, but would be happier with a source for this statement.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I'm too late in answering, but while it's known fact that the Cassini server doesn't support integrated pipeline mode, you can still test locally using the classic pipeline by adding it to the httpModules section of system.web in your web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    .
    .
    .
    <!-- HTTP Modules using Classic Pipeline -->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="YourHttpModule" type="ACME.YourHttpModule"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <!-- HTTP Modules using Integrated Pipeline -->
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="YourHttpModule" type="ACME.YourHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

You'd probably want to remove the httpModules section from your production web.config.

Comment: I tried adding the module in web.config as per your advice, and it still throws the PlatformNotSupported exception. In my case, I am trying to use Headers.Remove(), on an event of the HttpModule. Using VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

Got this today while running in visual studio 2012. Found the reason was visual studio launched the old web server that comes with 2010 and as explained above it can't work there. Changed to IIS Express by right click on properties, choose "Web" tab and and selecting IIS Express option. Then launching debug mode will start in IIS Express and this aparently supports operations such as `Request.Headers.Add` or whatever caused your exception.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you can't enable IIS Express for whatever reason (for example, company security prohibits it), changing `Request.Headers.Add()` to `Request.AddHeaders()` will usually fix this issue, too.