# ASP.NET default static handler called instead of my configured handler

Tags: asp.net, web-config

My web config has the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="myproxy.ashx/*" type="PSAMap.MyProxy"/>
...
  </httpHhandlers>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
  <modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </modules>
...
</system.webServer>
```

But a url like http://www.mysite.com/myAppName/myproxy.ashx/test/picture.jpg
fails because the static file handler can't find it.  I need EVERY url whose path starts with "myproxy.ashx" to go through the handler.  Did I not specify "runAllManagedModulesForAllReaquests" properly?  This is IIS on Windows 2008 Server in an application pool using the classic pipeline and .Net 2.0.   Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I left out an important detail - I was only trying to get this to work so far in my development environment using the Cassini web server that comes with Visual Studio...
When I changed the web.config of the application running under IIS - it worked correctly!

I was not aware of the differences in how the web.config specified handlers are implemented in development vs IIS.  So anyone trying to get standard looking URLs (no query strings) that look like a static file (like http://www.yoursite.com/yourapp/customhandler.ashx/folder/file.ext) the Cassini server will ALWAYS call the default static handler for these.  But if you have httphandler rules with a path specifying your handler class for urls starting with "customhandler.ashx" (in this example) IIS should correctly call this handler for you.  You may need the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" attribute in the modules setting as well.

Hope someone finds this useful.

This is the question/answer that pointed this out to me: [VS2010 development web server does not use integrated-mode HTTP handlers/modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708187/vs2010-development-web-server-does-not-use-integrated-mode-http-handlers-modules)